# Why 2 way merge sorting is more efficient than one way merge sorting

Tags: sorting, merge, external-sorting

I am reading about external sorting from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting), and need to understand why 2 phase merging is more efficient than 1 phase merging.

> Wiki : However, there is a limitation to single-pass merging. As the
>   number of chunks increases, we divide memory into more buffers, so
>   each buffer is smaller, so we have to make many smaller reads rather
>   than fewer larger ones.
>
> Thus, for sorting, say, 50 GB in 100 MB of RAM, using a single merge
>   pass isn't efficient: the disk seeks required to fill the input
>   buffers with data from each of the 500 chunks (we read 100MB / 501 ~
>   200KB from each chunk at a time) take up most of the sort time. Using
>   two merge passes solves the problem. Then the sorting process might
>   look like this:

```
Run the initial chunk-sorting pass as before.
Run a first merge pass combining 25 chunks at a time, resulting in 20 larger sorted chunks.
Run a second merge pass to merge the 20 larger sorted chunks.
```

Could anyone give me a simple example to understand this concept well. I am particularly confused about allocating more `buffers` in 2 phase merging.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is random access overhead, average rotational delay is around 4 ms, average seek time around 9 ms, so say 10 ms average access time, versus an average transfer rate around 150 mega-bytes per second. So the average access overhead takes about the same time as it does to read or write 1.5 megabytes.

Large I/O's reduce the relative overhead of access time. If data is read or written 10 mega bytes at a time, the overhead is reduced to 15%. Using the wiki example 100MB of working buffer and 25 chunks to merge, plus one chunk for writes, that's 3.8 megabyte chunks, in which case random access overhead is about 39%.

On most PC's, it's possible to allocate enough memory for a 1GB working buffer, so 26 chunks at over 40 mega bytes per chunk, reducing random access overhead to 3.75%. 50 chunks would be about 20 megabytes per chunk, with random access overhead around 7.5%.

Note that even with 50 chunks, it's still a two pass sort, the first pass uses all of the 1gb buffer to do a memory sort, then writes sorted 1gb chunks. The second pass merges all 50 chunks that result in the sorted file.

The other issue with 50 chunks, is that a  min heap type method is needed to maintain sorted information in order to determine which element of which chunk is the smallest of the 50 and gets moved to the output buffer. After an element is moved to the output buffer, a new element is moved into the heap and then the heap is re-heapified, which takes about 2 log2(50) operations, or about 12 operations. This is better than the simple approach of doing 49 compares to determine the smallest element from a group of 50 elements when doing the 50 way merge. The heap is composed of structures, the current element, which chunk this is (file position or file), the number of elements left in the chunk, ... .